# Empty column values mapping to java enum using ORMlite

Tags: java, ormlite

How do I map empty or unknown values to the `enum` in java. I am using Ormlite.

```
@DatabaseField(canBeNull=false, columnName=COLUMN_NAME_DEVICE_TYPE,  
     dataType=DataType.ENUM_STRING)
private DeviceType deviceType;
```

And here is my enum

```
public enum DeviceType {

    iPhone, iPad, Android,
    OSX, Windows, Windows8,
    WP7, WP8, Blackberry,
    Browser, Facebook, Unknown;

    @JsonCreator
    public static DeviceType parse(String s) {
        for (DeviceType t : values()) {
            if (t.name().toLowerCase().equals(s)) {
                return t;
            }
        }
        return Unknown;
    }

    @JsonValue
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Am always getting the following exception:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get enum value of '' for field FieldType:name=deviceType,class=MyEntity

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on data in database. I guess that this row has empty string '' for which no enum exists.